# Netty 4.1.51.Final has a bug in Http File Upload

Tags: java, http, file-upload, netty

Netty 4.1.51.Final has a bug in Http File Upload.

When I use HttpPostRequestDecoder to receive file uploaded but only get an incomplete file. The method offer() may not put segmented file body into one file because I test the Sum of bytes is true but inputChannel.size() is false.

If change the version to Netty 4.1.49.Final, everything is OK!

Here is my code:

```
package com.cauliflower.netty.handler;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.*;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.*;
import io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class HttpUploadHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpObject> {

    public HttpUploadHandler() {
        super(false);
    }

    private static final HttpDataFactory factory = new DefaultHttpDataFactory(true);
    private static final String FILE_UPLOAD = "/home/joker/Desktop/";
    private static final String URI = "/upload";
    private HttpPostRequestDecoder httpDecoder;
    HttpRequest request;

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final HttpObject httpObject)
            throws Exception {
        if (httpObject instanceof HttpRequest) {
            request = (HttpRequest) httpObject;
            if (request.method().equals(HttpMethod.POST)) {
                httpDecoder = new HttpPostRequestDecoder(factory, request);
                httpDecoder.setDiscardThreshold(0);
            } else {
                ctx.fireChannelRead(httpObject);
            }
        }
        if (httpObject instanceof HttpContent) {
            if (httpDecoder != null) {
                final HttpContent chunk = (HttpContent) httpObject;
                httpDecoder.offer(chunk);
                if (chunk instanceof LastHttpContent) {
                    writeChunk(ctx);
                    httpDecoder.destroy();
                    httpDecoder = null;
                    HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK);
                    ByteBuf byteBuf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer("0".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    response.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_LENGTH, byteBuf.readableBytes());
                    response.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
                    ctx.write(response);
                    ctx.write(byteBuf);
                    ctx.writeAndFlush(LastHttpContent.EMPTY_LAST_CONTENT);
                }
                ReferenceCountUtil.release(httpObject);
            } else {
                ctx.fireChannelRead(httpObject);
            }
        }

    }

    private void writeChunk(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws IOException {
        while (httpDecoder.hasNext()) {
            InterfaceHttpData data = httpDecoder.next();
            if (data != null && InterfaceHttpData.HttpDataType.FileUpload.equals(data.getHttpDataType())) {
                final FileUpload fileUpload = (FileUpload) data;
                final File file = new File(FILE_UPLOAD + fileUpload.getFilename());
                try (FileChannel inputChannel = new FileInputStream(fileUpload.getFile()).getChannel();
                     FileChannel outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(file).getChannel()) {
                    System.out.println(inputChannel.size());
                    outputChannel.transferFrom(inputChannel, 0, inputChannel.size());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        if (httpDecoder != null) {
            httpDecoder.cleanFiles();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please file a github issue if you suspect a bug or contact on mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

yes,it's a bug ~  4.1.52 already fixed...
[issues](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/10449)